# How can i list airport names in world on an auto complete textview in android

Tags: android

I'm trying to develop an app which needs to list airport names in world on an android autocomplete textview. I m trying to use google places api. But couldn't do it. What is the best way to do this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what issues r u facing with google places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey arya you can go through this tutorial for reference , i found this tutorial very useful have a look-
[google places and maps](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/)

in this tutorial you can replace `cafe/Restaurants` with `airports` and increase the radius size.

Comment: Are there any simple tutorials to refer. Thanks

Comment: hi i am giving some links refer it- [link1](http://karnshah8890.blogspot.in/2013/03/google-places-api-tutorial.html)     [link2](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-google-places-api-example/)                                                                               [link3](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/google-play-services-using-the-places-api--cms-23715)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Google places/Autocomplete api with the filter as *airport*.
You could run an async thread to fetch the result via their api or use their library to do the same. Check the below link for more.

https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/start

https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types

Also I suggest using a simple textview with a recyclerview below it for pure ui purposes. Basically the user has more space when the results are displayed on the entire screen than via an autocomplete view. This upto your choice.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem too. Sadly, there is no way to correctly filter for airports using google places api for now. The only sets of filters that work are TYPE_ESTABLISHMENTS, TYPE_GEOCODE , TYPE_ADDRESS ... [see table 3](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table3) for a list of supported filters for autocomplete